# ParametricNDsolve and Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

Currently, I'm trying to solve a differential equation using the function ParametricNDsolve and then use Manipulate function in order to see what happens when the diameter changes so I can find the one that fits my experimental results better.
The problem that I'm having is that the results that I got don't make any sense.
This is a code that I have so far:

```
    exp = 920*(4/3)*3.14*(dia/2)^3 *
    v'[t] == (-(0.5*v[t]*
         v[t]*3.1415 *1000* (dia^2)) *(24/((v[t]* 
           dia)/(0.0000010023))*(1 + 
          0.15*(((v[t]*dia)/0.0000010023)^0.687)))) + ((1000*(4/
          3)*3.14*(dia/2)^3*9.8) - (920*(4/3)*3.14*(dia/2)^3*9.8));
s = ParametricNDSolve[{exp, v[0.0] == 0}, v, {t, 0.0000, 5}, {dia}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[ Evaluate[v[dia][t] /. s], {t, 0.0000, 5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100], {dia, 0.002, 0.01}]
```

and this is the result that I have for dia = 0.0025:
[image]
and when I solve the same equation using NDsolve with dia= 0.0025 I get the result that I'm expecting:[image]
Does anyone know why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use this code  `Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[v[dia][t] /. s], {t, 0.0000, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> All], {dia, 0.002, 0.01}]`

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!